# Any suggestion about how I can avoid type mismatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, types

I read HTML file from the web and I am attempting to parse the texts

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt')
>>> r.status
404
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(r.data)

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

It appears that type mismatch is occurring but I failed to know the solution.

Comment: The response status is 404 but you're still try to access the data?

Comment: the correct url is http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt (notice the `-0` in the file name)

Comment: Use the `text` attribute instead of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The Python "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" occurs when we try to use a string pattern to match a bytes object. To solve the error use the     decode() method.

For more clarity you could check this link out: [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-cannot-use-a-string-pattern-on-bytes-like-object#:~:text=The%20Python%20%22TypeError%3A%20cannot%20use,%27utf%2D8%27](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-cannot-use-a-string-pattern-on-bytes-like-object#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20%22TypeError%3A%20cannot%20use,%27utf%2D8%27))%20.